# How to set div's height in css and html

Tags: html, css

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. I wrote in my html:

```
<div style="height:100px;" class="span12">
asdfashdjkfhaskjdf
</div>
```

Why the height is not 100px when I open that page?

---

> For posterity, the original code was : `<div height="100px">`

Comment: try `style="height: 100px; "`

Comment: you're unaware of a _major breakthrough_ for web page designers http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html

Comment: That's not an edit, that's a new question...

Comment: and you're also unaware of the fact that changing the question will make answers pointless

Comment: For posterity, original code was : <div height="100px">

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To write inline styling use:

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
asdfashdjkfhaskjdf
</div>
```

Inline styling serves a purpose however, it is not recommended in most situations.

The more "proper" solution, would be to make a separate CSS sheet, include it in your HTML document, and then use either an ID or a class to reference your div.

if you have the file structure:

```
index.html
>>/css/
>>/css/styles.css
```

Then in your HTML document between `<head>` and `</head>` write:

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then, change your div structure to be:

```
<div id="someidname" class="someclassname">
    asdfashdjkfhaskjdf
</div>
```

In css, you can reference your div from the ID or the CLASS.

To do so write:

```
.someclassname { height: 100px; }
```

OR

```
#someidname { height: 100px; }
```

Note that if you do both, the one that comes further down the file structure will be the one that actually works.

For example...  If you have:

```
.someclassname { height: 100px; }

.someclassname { height: 150px; }
```

Then in this situation the height will be 150px.

**EDIT:**

To answer your secondary question from your edit, probably need `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: visible;` .  You could also do this:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div style="height:100px;">
        asdfashdjkfhaskjdf
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
And if I want to set in percent, how should I write?

Comment: <div style="height:75%;">ASDF</div>

Comment: The question just changed, that's not fair-play

Answer (score 22):

```
<div style="height: 100px;"> </div>
```

OR

```
<div id="foo"/> and set the style as #foo { height: 100px; }
<div class="bar"/> and set the style as .bar{ height: 100px;  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I do not know why there was a downvote, I upvoted to make it higher.