# HTML 5 div height:100% is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some problem on my div height part. I was trying to make the div height to 100% but its not working. If I didnt use the html 5 my code works fine. [This is the link](http://www.iconis.com.my) where i have included the live website with the following error.

This is my style.css code :

```
.slide {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}

#slide1 {
  background-color: #00B4FF;

}

#slide2 {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#slide3 {
  background-color: #00B4FF;
  height: 700px;
}

#slide4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slide5 {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#slide6 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 350px;
}

#slide7 {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

I have tried manually changing the height to 100% in each of the #slide id but still its not working.

Comment: Try looking at these two posts: **1.** [how to set divs height in css and html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068665/how-to-set-divs-height-in-css-and-html) **2.** [CSS: Set Div height to 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366548/css-set-div-height-to-100-pixels)

Comment: Your padding for `.slide` seems to be issue

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem here. Can you give a better explanation or post a desired result screenshot?

Comment: @Austin yes i have looked into it but still its not helping for my case

Comment: @Typist if its the issue are there any way to solve it?

Comment: @user3663313 Is there anyway you could try making a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this? JSFiddle lets you emulate snippet code which we can edit directly for you. Hit `Save` when you are done and post the url. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Austin here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mE8uQ/

Comment: Your site link is down or not responsive so I cannot see a live demo of what is suppose to occur. So what is it that will be sliding? Like when you click on the image/name?

Comment: @Austin try clicking on it again www.iconis.com.my because its working fine here actually. i have used the parallax effect on my site so that each time i click on a menu items it slides down to the particular item.

Comment: Ok there it goes, so we are talking about these colored sections, like "founding members" I assume, now when you say you want them to be at 100% div height, what exactly do you mean? Do you want them all on row? Do you want them to somehow take over the entire screen? What exactly? a simple edited `paint` image may help a bit for me to visual what you are trying to do.

Comment: To add on, I am guessing you want each screen "full-sized" as you click the down arrow. As in, each button click scrolls to a full screen size, is that right?

Comment: @Austin exactly each slide should be fit in full size into the screen

Comment: Answer added, I will keep updating it as necessary. You have a lot going on with the site, but I will try to help you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try something as such

```
#slide1{
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #00B4FF;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mE8uQ/7/)** (each slide has it within its CSS)

**ALSO** remove the styling CSS you have within `.slide`, that will interfere with your `#slide` styling.

On initial load, each height should be full screen relative to each `#slide`

Test this out on your site though as you have many layers of items occurring that are not reflected in the JSFiddle which could interfere with this code.

**EDIT** Just fixed roughly 20 lines of incorrect HTML for you, continuing to add updates.

**EDIT 2** I think the best way to do this is if you resize the div per button click (your down arrow). Since I cannot see these trigger's however I cannot be much help. Maybe try looking into this [Jquery Change Height based on Browser Size/Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838137/jquery-change-height-based-on-browser-size-resize)?

It's is slightly impossible to pre-set all the possible heights of each div, without knowing how the browser will be. Using JQuery as posted above will make your site a lot more dynamic/smoother.