# How to show an OpenStreetMap map in a div?

Tags: html, css, openstreetmap

How do I show an OpenStreetMap map in a (smaller) div?

I use this code:

```
<html><body>
  <div id="mapdiv" width="500" height="300"></div>
  <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(3.45, 51.5)
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
          );

    var zoom=13;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
  </script>
</body></html>
```

but the map is shown full over the webpage.

Comment: Can you show the outcome?

Comment: `<div id="mapdiv" width="500" height="300"></div>` This is wrong. you want [to use CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068665/how-to-set-divs-height-in-css-and-html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
<div id="mapdiv" style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want a location on the map to be selected by the user in openstreetmap.
And I send that position to the server through the form.

Comment: You are asking instead of giving answer to the question !