# Resizing div container

Tags: html, css, resize

I'm fiddling around with this 3D object viewer for my website, I want to embed the viewer in my website, but it pops up on the page way too big.. Can some one tell me how I change the scale of this div?

```
<div id="fyu_9y1p82ic59" class="fyu_container fyu_vertical fyu_nomax"></div><script src="https://fyu.se/embed?v=3.0"></script><script>FYU.add("9y1p82ic59", "fyu_9y1p82ic59", {autoplay:1});</script>
```

Now I tried changing the div height, but this doesn't change the size of the actual player, it just cuts off the entire bottom part of it. How do I fix this?

[Click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReXTR.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set div's height in css and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068665/how-to-set-divs-height-in-css-and-html)