# Getting rid of the height attribute of a <div> tag

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

So, I have to build a page in SharePoint, and I have to get rid of some whitespace at the top of the page that is left when I took out a toolbar.
The code causing the problem is:

```
<div id="s4-ribbonrow" style="height: 126px;">
```

When I inspect element and change the height to 0px, it looks perfect. However, when I actually go in the CSS and try to change it to 0, it doesn't work. Is there any way to get this to work?

Edit: Whoops, I somehow posted it without posted the code I have.

Comment: I believe you can also set in the div tag `<div style="height:100px;">` also more answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068665/how-to-set-divs-height-in-css-and-html

Answer (score 1):

Inline styles will always take precedence over a rule in your stylesheet. Remove the 'style' attribute from the element and the stylesheet will be used.

Comment: _“Inline styles will always take precedence over a rule in your stylesheet.”_ - no, not always - they can be overwritten from within the stylesheet. https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813220/how-can-i-override-inline-styles-with-external-css

Comment: Good catch. `!important` is the one gotcha that can trump the normal precedence of CSS. I deserve that for speaking in absolutes. I guess an inline style with that rule would be the ultimate be-all and end-all CSS declaration